# jQuery Language Translation is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-plugins

I want to translate my html page from English to arabic and arabic to english.

I am using **"[jquery.translate.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery-i18n-1.0.0.js.txt)"** plugin.
this plugin will translate my language

Am using json file to indicate the changes in the language using span id of the HTML elements.
       **langfiles-ar-SA.json**

```
  {
  "ProfileSpan" : "Profile",
  "FrinedsSpan" : "Invite",
  "FreepointsSpan" : "Points",
  "PhonenumberSpan" : "Phone",
  }
```

similarly another json file as 
        **langfiles-ar-SA.json**

```
  {
  "ProfileSpan" : "Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù„Ù�",
  "FrinedsSpan" : "Ø¯Ø¹ÙˆØ©",
  "FreepointsSpan" : "Ø§Ù„Ù†Ù‚Ø§Ø·",
  "PhonenumberSpan" : "Ø¨Ø­Ø« Ù…ØªÙ‚Ø¯Ù",
  }
```

In html I added the three js files
      **js/jquery.js, js/jquery.translate.js, js/translationManagement.js**
  The json files are in the folder in the webcontent.
   My javascript is:

```
    function Intialize(){
 $('#EnglishLanguageLink').click(function() {
  var eng = 'en-US';
  changeLanguage(eng);
  return false;
     });
$('#ArabicLanguageLink').click(function() {
    var ara = 'ar-SA';  
  changeLanguage(ara);
  return false;
     });
    }

    function changelanguage(newLanguage){
     $(this).translate("languages/langfiles.json", newLanguage);
    }
```

If I click the english language link and tamil language link it goes to the top of the page. But the translation doesnt happen. What error am doing. Please suggest a way to solve this. Any suggestions Please?
      Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be because your `changelanguage` function will actually be running in the `window` object's scope. This means that `this` in `changelanguage()` will actually be referencing the `window` object and not the other elements. To fix this, pass the object into your function like so:

```
function changelanguage(newLanguage, obj){
    $(obj).translate("languages/langfiles.json", newLanguage);
}
```

And then in your click handlers, change the call to this:

```
changeLanguage(eng, this);
```

And obviously change eng for the Arabic link.

I'm not entirely sure if that's what variable `.translate` should be running on, but it seems weird that you would run it on the `window` object.